# Objective-C use of dot notation on synthesized properties ivars

Tags: objective-c, syntax, properties

So let's say I've got a synthesized property for a **UITextField** which I have named **field1**. From my understanding is that you should use **self.field1 = newValue** to change the field1 value. By using the dot notation you automatically use the created setter by the compiler. (Or use it without dot notation **[self setField1:newValue]**)

But I've seen examples where they use this same dot notation method on setting the field1's ivars like:

```
field1.text = @"Text";
```

Does this mean that when declaring a property you can automatically use dot notation on all that property's ivars? Or is this possible only because in that UITextField class the ivar "text" is declared as a property? Say if text wasn't declared as a property would the correct way to set the text ivar be:

```
[field1 setText:@"Text"]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given:

```
@interface Foo:NSObject
{
   int bar;
}

@property int age;

- (int)bar;
- (void)setBar:(int)anInt;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize age;

- (int)bar { return bar; }
- (void)setBar:(int)anInt { bar = anInt; }
@end
```

You can:

```
- (void)makeMyFunkThePFunk
{
   Foo *foo = [Foo new];
   foo.bar = 5;
   [foo setBar: 42];

   [foo setAge: 29];
   foo.age = 42;

   [foo setAge: foo.bar];
   [foo setBar: foo.age];
}
```

@property is nothing more than a bit of syntax for declaring setter/getter methods more easily, including the automatic synthesis of both the instance variables and the implementation methods, if desired.

The dot syntax is shorthand for a method call.  Any "dot" expression can be turned into an equivalent method call and using the dot syntax does not require an @property declaration.

Comment: So dot notation can be used as an equivalent to the setter/getter method as long as there is a set and get method for the ivar? (I'm assuming that if you didn't have the bar and setBar methods you can't use the foo.bar call?)

Comment: Exactly.  Dot syntax and @property are orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got my bases covered then. Though it is confusing. I think I will stick to coding with brackets. Feels that there will be less confusion that way.

Comment: It is a matter of taste.  Do what comes most naturally to you.   There are very minor subtle differences between dot and method calls, but only at compile time;  the generated code is the same.  Namely, the dot syntax is more tightly type-safe validated at compile time.

Comment: @bbum Is there any publicly available information to show that dot syntax being more tightly type-safe validated at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

> Or is this possible only because in that UITextField class the ivar "text" is declared as a property?

This is correct. You can use the dot notation on anything that's declared as a property.

Comment: You can use dot syntax on any setter/getter, no @property needed

Comment: Can you give me an example please.

Comment: Yes.  See my answer.  While Amorya's answer is correct, the implication that @property is required is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
field1.text = @"Text";
```

and

```
[field1 setText:@"Text"]
```

are equivalent, and you would expect them to be, but `field1.text` could call almost any method if the property was defined differently: `@property(getter=someOtherMethod)NSString * text;`

Answer (score 1):

Property declarations do not apply automatically to ivars' components.

In your example,

`field1.text = @"Text";`

`text` is also declared as a property in `UITextField`. This is why you can use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property of properties with dot notation.

```
self.field1.text = @"test";
```

There's nothing special going on. `self.field1` returns a `UITextField`. `text` is the name of a property of that text field.

---

In response to your comment, `self.field1` accesses the property, `field1` is the ivar. My example given above is exactly equivalent to:

```
[[self field1] setText:@"test"];
```

Either one will work, but you generally want to use the property accessors like: `self.field1.text`

Comment: If using dot notation. What would be the correct way actually to access that property? Either self.field1.text = @"test"; (as you wrote) or field1.text = @"test";

Comment: I'm not completely following you here. What's the difference between the two calls you examplified and these two calls: field1.text = @"test" and [field1 setText:@"test"] ?

Comment: No difference at all but syntax.  Compiled result is identical.